# How to fix the delay in the first use of a shader?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I ran the OpenGL ES Analysis tool from Instruments in my app, and it stated that after compiling the shader, I should make a call to glDrawArrays in a prewarming pass. So I checked the time of some shaders I wrote, and indeed the first time the program run it is much slower.

In my code I have a generic shader loader, which doesn't know the shader uniforms/attributes, it just compile it. And it seems that the best place to prewarm the shader is there (so I don't need to add glDrawArrays everywhere). I tryed adding this in my shader loader:

```
glUseProgram(prog);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 0);
```

It fixed the delay, but since I'm not setting any uniforms/attributes I'm not sure if it is safe. Also it somehow looks like a workaround. What is the best way to prewarm the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is (almost) perfectly safe. The uniforms are not a problem since they do contain some default values. As for the attributes, it is not a problem either since you are not emitting any vertices.

On the other hand, this may be the easiest way to prewarm the shaders, but may not be the best one. A similar techniques were used back at a time to prewarm textures (to fill the texture cache). It was usually done by rendering a few frames while not displaying the output. This was seen for example in Unreal Tournament, it displayed "Precaching" for a short while after loading the level. I'd suggest doing the same.

Comment: Excellent piece of information though this is the first time I am reading about shaders prewarm. Do you have any literature on that? It would be most helpful.

Cheers

Comment: Well, because all the GPU-related implementation details are vendor specific and mostly confidential, i'd say there is no solid piece of information on that (because noone really knows and it always changes). But the concepts stay the same, if there is a resource that is cached or lazily loaded, just render a few frames to fill the cache and cause the resource to load. There's not much else to it ...